# 1 kb swf file created when building to flash in unity

Tags: unity, flash

I am trying to build a project in flash that I have made. It goes through its building process, but when it is done the swf file that it creates is 1 kb in size. I am not sure what I am doing wrong or what is going on. I have built to flash before and never ran into this problem until recently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey I figured out a solution that works. All I did was switch the platform to something else then switched back to flash and was able to get it to work